# Getting multiple layers for a decoder from a trained autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, autoencoder, decoder

I am trying to make a decoder with multiple layers from a trained autoencoder. Unfortunately the decoder doesn't seem to reconstruct the test images.

I have been following the keras blog https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html. However, I made slight changes and added another Dense layer for encoding and decoding in the autoencoder.

Here is my autoencoder model:

```
encoding_dim = 18  
input_img = Input(shape=(784,), name='img_input')

encoded_1 = Dense(100, activation='relu', name='encoded_1')(input_img)
encoded_2 = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu', name='encoded_2')(encoded_1)

decoded_1 = Dense(100, activation='sigmoid', name='decoded_1')(encoded_2)
decoded_2 = Dense(784,  activation='sigmoid', name='decoded_2')(decoded_1)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded_2)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

hist = autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=100,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))

plot_model(autoencoder, to_file= 'model.png')
autoencoder.summary()
```

Now I define my encoder and decoder models:

```
# Making the encoder model
new_encoded_1 = autoencoder.layers[1]
new_encoded_2 = autoencoder.layers[2]

encoder = Model(input_img, new_encoded_2.output)
encoder.summary()

#The decoder model
encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,), name='encoded_input')
new_decoded_1 = autoencoder.layers[-2](encoded_input)
new_decoded_2 = autoencoder.layers[-1](new_decoded_1)

decoder = Model(encoded_input, new_decoded_2)
decoder.summary()
```

Finally I use the test dataset on the encoder and the decoder but the reconstructed images did not resemble the test images at all.

```
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)
```

It seems like I am missing something small because in the one layer decoder seems to work well with the one layer decoder.

```
n = 10  # how many digits we will display
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
for i in range(n):
    # display original
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()


    # display reconstruction
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1 + n)
    plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()

plt.show()
```

Comment: I changed the activation function to Relu in the first dense layer instead of sigmoid and I got the loss function to converge must faster. Apparently everything works now!